# Make laplace-expansion more efficient

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I created a little program that is able to calculate the determinant of a matrix in C++. I used laplace-expansion, although I know that there are more efficient ways to do it:

```
double getDeterminantLaplace(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {

    int dimension = vect.size();

    if(dimension == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(dimension == 1) {
        return vect[0][0];
    }

    //Formula for 2x2-matrix
    if(dimension == 2) {
        return vect[0][0] * vect[1][1] - vect[0][1] * vect[1][0];
    }

    double result = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {

        //Submatrix
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> subVect(dimension - 1, std::vector<double> (dimension - 1));
        for(int m = 1; m < dimension; m++) {
            int z = 0;
            for(int n = 0; n < dimension; n++) {
                if(n != i) {
                    subVect[m-1][z] = vect[m][n];
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }

        //recursive call
        result = result + sign * vect[0][i] * getDeterminantLaplace(subVect);
        sign = -sign;
    }

    return result;
}
```

My question now is: How can this algorithm be made more efficient?

One of my ideas is to not create the "submatrices" and just work with the original matrix, but I don't really know how to do it. What do you think about this idea? How can I do this in C++?

Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: You could pass `vect` by reference.

Comment: If you have multiple cores, you could use for example openmp to parallize the outher for iteration with i. The only thing, for i = 0 up to i = dimension changes is i itself and sign as I can see, and if I remember my math course correctly, you could determine sign value by i, but for that I am not quite sure ;)

Comment: If you want to get the result as efficiently as possible, and this isn't some kind of homework, I'd highly suggest you use an optimized library to do algebra, e.g. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). There's simply no way you're going to get close to it in performance without spending an ungodly amount of time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first, trivial optimization is not to recurse when the current element is zero. This will give you an instant speed-up on sparse matrices.

The next optimization is what you already suggested: Do not to create all submatrices. You can do that by creating an index vector. For example, if your original matrix has 4×4 elements, you recurse with the following index vectors:

```
0: {1, 2, 3}
1: {0, 2, 3}
2: {0, 1, 3}
3: {0, 1, 2}
```

You don't need to create the index vector from scratch each time: Start with the subvector that is the current vector without its front, then overwrite the i-th place with the i-th entry of the current ubvector.

When you access the element `s[r][c]` of the submatrix, access element `a[r + top][col[c]]` of the original matrix. You can determine the index of the top row from the dimensions of the current column vector and the original matrix.

You never create submatrices, only sub-column vectors. Split your function in two: One public function as front-end, which calls the recursive worker function.

This will speed up the calculation somewhat, but unfortunately, this improvement will not buy you much when your matrices grow. Let's look at the 4×4 matrix again. In the first recursion step, you will consider these 3×3 submatrices:

```
1, 2, 3     0, 2, 3     0, 1, 3     0, 1, 2
```

From there, you will calculate these 2×2 submatrices:

```
   2, 3        2, 3        1, 3        1, 2
1,    3     0,    3     0,    3     0,    2
1, 2        0, 2,       0, 1,       0, 1,
```

Notice that these 12 indices are realy just 6 different pairs. You'll calculate each of them twice. This will get worse the bigger your original matrix is. A solution to this is memoizing: Once you have calculated the determinant of a certain submatrix, store the value in an associated array. Before calculating a submatrix, check whether you have already done that and if so, just return the value you calculated earlier.

This will speec up your function, but it comes at a price: It will create many entries in the associated array.

Anyway, here's the code that implements all optimizations I've described:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

double subdet(const std::vector<std::vector<double> > &a,
    const std::vector<int> &col,
    std::map<std::vector<int>, double> &memo)
{
    int dim = col.size();
    int top = a.size() - dim;

    if (memo.find(col) != memo.end()) {
        return memo[col];
    }   

    if (dim == 2) return a[top + 0][col[0]] * a[top + 1][col[1]]
                       - a[top + 0][col[1]] * a[top + 1][col[0]];

    double result = 0.0;
    int sign = 1;

    std::vector<int> ncol(&col[1], &col[dim]);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (a[top][col[i]]) {
            double d = subdet(a, ncol, memo);

            result = result + sign * a[top][col[i]] * d;
        }

        sign = -sign;

        if (i + 1 < dim) ncol[i] = col[i];
    }

    memo[col] = result;
    return result;
}

double det(const std::vector<std::vector<double> > a)
{
    int dim = a.size();

    if (dim == 0) return 1.0;
    if (dim == 1) return a[0][0];

    std::vector<int> col(dim);
    std::map<std::vector<int>, double> memo;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) col[i] = i;

    return subdet(a, col, memo);
}
```

Notes: The map (a binary tree with O(log *n*) lookup) should really be an unodered map (a hash table with O(1) lookup), but I couldn't get it to work, because I'm bad at C++. Sorry about that.

There's probably room for optimization of the lookup key, too: One can enumerate the possible index vectors or use a bit mask, perhaps, thereby saving memory in the hash map. It's no good string references to the column-index vector, because it's short-lived and we're swapping around in it a lot, so it's not constant.

Of course, other algorithms are better suited for finding the determinat of large matrices. My answer focuses on improving the existing method.